# MySQL : Using alias inside a join condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(t2.profile_id, t3.profile_id) AS `profile_id`
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.some_coulmn
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t1.id = t3.some_coulmn
LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4
    ON profile_id = t4.some_column
```

I'm trying to use an alias (`profile_id`) inside my join condition. It fails. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Repeat the expression in the condition.

Comment: I did, the query keeps going and never finishes.

Comment: Maybe some other transaction with uncommitted changes blocks it. Or it just take a long time because of large data quantity and/or poor indexing. Gots nothing to do with alias being unusable in a join condition though.

Comment: Does it fail with an error message?

Comment: @stickybit you're right, it was just taking too long, but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases defined in th `SELECT` clause cannot be used in the join conditions. This is because the `FROM` clause is evaluated *before* the `SELECT` clause.

If I followed you correctly, you probably want:

```
SELECT t1.*, IFNULL(t2.profile_id, t3.profile_id) AS `profile_id`
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.id = t2.some_coulm
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t1.id = t3.some_coulm
LEFT JOIN table4 AS t4
    ON IFNULL(t2.profile_id, t3.profile_id) = t4.some_column
```